# Can I use Windows On-Screen Keyboard with Oculus Rift's Virtual Desktop?

Tags: virtual-desktop, mouse-cursor, on-screen-keyboard, xbox-one, oculus-rift

[Virtual Desktop](https://www.oculus.com/experiences/rift/911715622255585/) is an app for the Oculus Rift VR headset that allows you to use your PC in VR.  You control the mouse using the joystick of your Xbox One controller.  But I'd like to control the keyboard as well, without having to use my physical keyboard.

Now Windows 10 has a built-in On-Screen Keyboard, but when I try to click the keys of the On-Screen Keyboard with my Xbox controller, somehow nothing happens.  Yet when I click the same keys using my physical mouse, it works.  So what's going on?  Is there any way to use the Windows On-Screen Keyboard while using the Virtual Desktop app?